# Find the Top 5 records in column B for the Top 5 records of Column A

Tags: sql

The question is regarding SQL query. I have a RootCause 1 and a RootCause 2 column options. The user selects the primary RootCause and if applicable, they select a secondary RootCause for futher detail. Id like to find/create a query that will allow me to select what Top 5 RootCausese in RC2 were selected for the RootCause in RC1.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  You can use this function with aggregation to get what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select rc1, rc2, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by rc1 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      group by rc1, rc2
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```